# How do I add a multicast route in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, routing, multicast

I have 2 interfaces on my desktop: one in a multicast enabled vlan, that has access to some udp streams, but otherwise unrouted, and one with internet access, but no multicast.

If only the multicast interface is enabled, I am able to play the streams, with VLC, for example. If I enable the second interface, I loose access to the multicast stream.

This happens due to a routing problem, as far as I can think. So I need to route the multicast request (IGMP and such) through the right interface, or something like that.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this on Windows 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried moving the network card that needs to multicast up in priority?

- Open `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections`
- Press your `ALT` key, then choose the `Advanced` menu and select `Advanced Settings`.
- Under `Adapters and Bindings`, move the multicast NIC above the Internet Access NIC in the `Connections` field.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Glad that helped.

Comment: +1. I was going to research the right syntax to add a static route pointing for the multicast range out the correct interface, but this solution is way better.

Comment: If you do this, wouldn't that make the gateway in the multicast enabled network your default gateway, causing all traffic without a specific route to try to go through that interface instead of the internet connected interface?

Comment: Could someone tell me, how to do the same in Windows 10 Enterprise?

Answer (score 1):

I will just add one information to accepted answer. In Windows 10 there in not anymore this settings available. It is based on metrics. So in a case of Windows 10 you need to setup manualy the metrics for network adapters to achieve same thing as described in accepted answer.